# TFS permissions overriding if a user is member of more group

Tags: permissions, visual-studio-2008, team-foundation-server

We are using VS2008 connected to TFS 2012.We made two groups,Developer and Incorporator. Incorporator group has CheckIn permission and Developer group doesn't. A Developer is member of both group. He must have CheckIn permission but it seems like permission inherited from Developer group overriding permissions of Incorporator group.But we need him to have permissions given to both groups i.e he must have checkin permission. Why this overriding happening?How to avoid this?

Answer (score 1):

In TFS deny always wins so don't use deny, just uncheck allow. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838712/tfs-2010-permissions-to-folders-and-files)

P.s. you don't let developers check in? Wtf